How to buffer tri-state GPIO pin for higher source/sink current?
Edit: I am not looking for a circuit to drive LEDs. I am looking for a generic solution to buffer a tri-state GPIO.  My mention below of the bi-color LEDs is only to explain why I need to maintain tri-state functionality.
I would like to control a bi-color LED using tri-state GPIO.  When HIGH it lights a green LED, when LOW it lights a red LED, and when High-Z (set as an input) it turns both LEDs off.  The LED circuit itself isn't important.  However, the problem is that the LEDs require more current than the GPIO pin can source/sink.  Therefore I need some sort of buffer that maintains the three states of the GPIO pin but can source/sink more current (say 50mA to be safe).  What are common ways to accomplish this?  I've been looking at datasheets of so-called tri-state buffers (e.g. SN74LVC1G125/6), but I haven't been able to come up with a circuit that actually maintains the input state given the logic tables.  I have 3.3V power source, and I only want to use a single GPIO pin.  If you have a solution, part numbers and schematics would be greatly appreciated.

Why is GPIO current not enough?  Which LED takes so much current? Which MCU you have driving it? The solutions with one IO pin are likely more expensive and complex than using two IO pins. Or some 1-wire expander.

"The LED circuit itself isn't important." Quite the opposite, info about the LED is mandatory.

@Justme GPIO is limited to 16mA, and I need to drive an LED with 20mA-30mA.  I'm also running out of GPIO.

@Raonoke the point is that I need to duplicate my GPIO pin but be able to provide more current.  You really don't need to know what's connected to it.  I explained the application only to explain why I need to keep the tri-state functionality.

I think that instead of trying to come up with a general "tri-state buffer" (which there are devices called that but they don't do what you want to do here), you should tailor the solution to the specific device you are trying to drive. As you can see, there are ways to drive an LED with a tristate output but they may not work for a different application.

This looks like an XY Problem. You want to drive a bidirectional LED, and you think the solution is a general tristate buffer, but that isn't necessarily the best solution for your problem.

@mattmunee - I understood what you need. Duplicating the GPIO pin with a beefier tri-state buffer doesn't cut it because that would require 2 GPIO pins. My point was that, in order to provide you a solution, it's important to know what type of LED (antiparallel, common anode/cathode, separate etc.) you have.

Here's a 'deluxe' expensive version, but parts count is still reasonable and the output current capability of the NCS2252s meets your 50mA constraint. R1..R4 are a 4-resistor network.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
You may need to split R6 into two in order to get acceptable brightness for both LEDs since they have different Vf and different brightness-current curves.

You've substantially changed the question, from what I can see, but anyway, here's the trivial adaptation of this idea to get what you say you want:

simulate this circuit

While this is a way to drive two LED's, this does not actually address my question.  I specifically want a generic solution that buffers the GPIO pin, providing a higher-current tri-state node that could be used for any GPIO application.  I want to convert my 10mA-limited GPIO pin into a 50mA-limited GPIO pin that can be used for anything requiring tri-state output.  Please forget about the LEDs.  That was included only to explain why I need to maintain the tri-state functionality.

See above. There is no trivial way to buffer a tristate output that I know of, so unless someone has come out with a chip for that purpose and it's otherwise acceptable you're usually better off using multiple outputs.

I appreciate the edited answer, and I'll study this.  To be clear, I have not edited the question.  I've only clarified what I'm looking for.  That's why there's no mention of LEDs in the title.  I was and am looking for a generic solution.  I assumed that this would be a really common need.  Truly thank you again for editing your solution to be more generic.

For voltage hungry LEDs, like blue, you'll need to have the full 3.3V available for the LED. Here's a solution using a single 8-pin IC, the LM393, containing two comparators:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
When the IO pin is high impedance, R1 and R2 produce +1.65V at IN. Otherwise the IO pin asserts 0V or +3.3V there. Those are the three possible values of \$V_{IN}\$, which is compared by comparators CMP1 and CMP2 against \$V_Y=+1.1V\$ and \$V_X=+2.2V\$ produced by R3, R4 and R5.
The comparators have open-collector outputs able to drive the LEDs directly, up to 16mA. CMP1 output goes low (lighting its LED) if \$V_{IN}>+2.2V\$, and CMP2 output goes low when \$V_{IN}<+1.1V\$.
If you have more than one of these to implement, you can re-use the signals at X and Y for all of them, without having to duplicate R3, R4 and R5 each time.
These comparators can't sink 50mA, though. For that amount of current you'll need to buffer their outputs, requiring transistors. If you have to add transistors, then there's probably a better transistor-only solution.

Update
Here's a tri-state buffer, like Jens' answer, that requires input current to activate its output. Unlike that other answer, this one inverts. I employ MOSFETs to keep input current under 1mA. You should use MOSFETS with \$V_{GS(TH)}<1.6V\$ for best results:

simulate this circuit
Switching speed is good, these are input and output voltages:

Output current can exceed 50mA:

Using BJTs instead, input current will increase (still under 2mA though). don't forget the base resistors:

simulate this circuit

The design can be adapted for use with LEDs, making almost the full 3.3V supply available to them:

simulate this circuit
These are LED currents resulting from the same sweeping input voltage from before:

On a side note, because this thing inverts, in can be modified with a single resistor to provide positive feedback, improving switching speed and noise immunity, and forcing all transistors into either cut-off or saturation:

simulate this circuit


While this is a way to drive two LED's, this does not actually address my question.  I specifically want a generic solution that buffers the GPIO pin, providing a higher-current tri-state node that could be used for any GPIO application.  I want to convert my 10mA-limited GPIO pin into a 50mA-limited GPIO pin that can be used for anything requiring tri-state output.  Please forget about the LEDs.  That was included only to explain why I need to maintain the tri-state functionality.

You have modified the question in between, the bidirectional LED is removed.
This circuit is a true three state buffer, no transistor is conducting without an input current. The saturation voltage across Q3 and Q4 is acceptable low.
The available output current is limited by R1, R2 and the current gain of Q3 and Q4. Actually there is no overcurrent protection.
The circuit is not very fast, at least R5 and R6 increase the turn off speed a bit.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
